# Using CGI Scope to Create a working URL

Tags: coldfusion

I am generating the url as:

```
http://localhost:8500/project1/list.cfm?category=55&secondary=72&view=&showall=0&sortby=price&sortdir=asc&_view=grid&price_tag_min=0&price_tag_max=134
```

using the following code:

```
<cfset sURL = request.siteurl & CGI.SERVER_NAME & ":" & CGI.SERVER_PORT & CGI.SCRIPT_NAME & "?" & CGI.QUERY_STRING>
```

now this repeats the query string which i want to avoid, like `price_tag_min & price_tag_max` and the values they own, i can have new values

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Not being sarcastic, but if you do not want to include the query string, well ... do not include the query string:  `& "?" & CGI.QUERY_STRING`

Comment: @leigh correct, but i want to include the variables which are rice_min and price_max, if i do not, it actually gets duplicated

Comment: So it sound like you want to use a loop to build up a query string that you really want. I suspect your avoid list is a) long and b) can change

Comment: so how i do i build it

Comment: could you treat the query string as a list, and go through the list and get the values you want?

Comment: sometimes javascript is better approach,i fixed it